# 'HtmlTestResult' object has no attribute '_count_relevant_tb_levels'. Did you mean: '_is_relevant_tb_level'?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

When I try running a test suite with assertEqual the suite fail with that message

```
    def test_validate_title(self):
        self.driver.get('https://facebook.com')
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, 'Chrome', '[ERROR] Title different')

    def test_validate_title2(self):
        self.driver.get('https://google.com')
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, 'Facebook', '[ERROR] Title different')

    def test_validate_title3(self):
        self.driver.get('https://youtube.com')
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, 'Chrome', '[ERROR] Title different')
    
    def tearDown(self):
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.quit()
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Test result: '))
```

I thinks that assertEqual do fail my suite because with another test the report is generated

Comment: Is this exactly how your code appears in your IDE? If so, then you have indenting errors that must be fixed.

Comment: No, in my IDE is good indenting. I fixed that there